# Format a string to specific format

Tags: c

```
    //take the buffer, format it into a **write test.c 4:[this is what I want written in the file]**

    void saveFile(Request request) {
    //user inputted save test.c 4:[this is what I want written in the file]
    char command[5] = "write";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        request[i] = command[i];
    }

}
```

The issue is my logic will format the string into writetest.c 4:[this is what I want written in the file]
I want to add space between write and the next char

Comment: Note that `command` is not a null-terminated byte string. When you make it such then perhaps use [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to format your strings? And then you don't need the `command` array anymore.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make much sense with the little information given in your questions. What is `Request`? How should we know that you really meant `char *` instead? It's hard to tell what the actual input to the function was, and what the actual output should be. Not to mention that you never explicitly say you want to replace the leading word `"save"` in the input with the word `"write"`.

Comment: For future questions please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue :)

```
void saveFile(char * request) {
//user inputted save test.c 4:[this is what I want written in the file]
char command[5] = "write";
char copyWithExtraBytes[1000];
strcpy_s(copyWithExtraBytes,strlen(request)+1, request);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(copyWithExtraBytes); ++i) {
    copyWithExtraBytes[i] = command[i];
    if (i == 4)
    {
        break;
    }
}
for (int i = 5; i < (strlen(copyWithExtraBytes))+1; ++i) {
    if (i ==5)
    {
        copyWithExtraBytes[5] = ' ';
        continue;
    } else
        {
            copyWithExtraBytes[i] = request[i -1];
            if (i == strlen(request))
            {
                copyWithExtraBytes[i+1] = request[i-1];
            }

        }
}
printf("%s",copyWithExtraBytes);
```

}

Comment: What your function basically is doing is `printf("write %s", request + strlen("save "));`